# SQLAlchemy insert list of dictionarys by batches

Tags: database, postgresql, python-3.x, insert, sqlalchemy

Im reading a file and constructing dictionarys per row read.

In a for loop im appending to a list those dictionarys, when the `len(list)` is bigger at 10K, i send the list to `con.execute(add.insert(list))` and clean the list.
The problem is the last list of dictionarys is not a 10K so i miss inserting the last batch.

I dont dont think building and inmemory large list of dictionarys and then iterate over the list would be a performatic way of handling this.

Is there a method in SQLAlchemy where i just send the dictionarys and set the size limit of the batch size so it handles the load by itself ? Or another workaround ...

```
    chunks.append(data_dict)
    if len(chunks) == 10000:
        con.execute(add.insert(chunks))
        del chunks[:]
```

.newb slqalchemy learner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a naive solution you can take advantage of the fact you can access the last variable in a for loop outside the loop. Adding a few other tweaks I think this will work:

```
for counter, data_dict in enumerate(data_dict_list):
    chunks.append(data_dict)
    if counter % 10000 == 0 and counter != 0:
        con.execute(add.insert(chunks))
        chunks = []
con.execute(add.insert(chunks))
```

If you want to take advantage of more SQLAlchemy features this docs page has an example of a bulk insert following a similar pattern:

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/faq/performance.html#i-m-inserting-400-000-rows-with-the-orm-and-it-s-really-slow

Comment: Thanks ACV it did help - with some minor tweaks it seems stable now.

Comment: Boa, valeu @JorgeVidinha ;)

Comment: :-) Ohoh foi joia mesmo. Valeu obrigado.